# Select the most RIGHT column, without nan value in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, and want to create a separate column. This columns must be based on the 'most right' value in a data frame. But, if the value is a nan/None, skip the column.

Data frame:

```
Column_0    Column_1    Column_2   Column_3     
nan            nan        nan        nan         
1              2          nan        nan
1              2          3          4
1              nan        3          nan
```

Output:

```
Column_Output
nan
2
4
3
```

I searched for solutions... but even finding the right search terms was causing me trouble. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by 'most right' value in dataframe? is it first value or last value in each column??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First forward filling missing values and then select last column:

```
df['Column_Output'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
   Column_0  Column_1  Column_2  Column_3  Column_Output
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN            NaN
1       1.0       2.0       NaN       NaN            2.0
2       1.0       2.0       3.0       4.0            4.0
3       1.0       NaN       3.0       NaN            3.0
```